# How to add Twitter Bootstrap dropdown items dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am adding drop down dynamically in java script using twitter bootstrap , but some how the drop down is not opening .

Below is the code and here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/szx4Y/281/

```
<div class="dropdown" >
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="downarrow dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown V</a>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').on('click','a[data-toggle="dropdown"]', function(){   
        if($(this).children().length <= 0){
            $(this).append( '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" >'+ '<li><a href="#">Edit</a></li><li><a href="#">Report</a></li><li><a href="#">Delete</a></li></ul>' );
            $(this).dropdown();
        }
    });              
});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to use  $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');

Comment: Thank You It is opening now . But surprisingly closing functionality is not working . I mean it just stays there forever . Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/szx4Y/282/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's "after" method instead of "append". According to the Bootstrap markup you want .dropdown-menu to be next to the link/button, not inside of it. Full code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="dropdown"]',
        function () {
            if ($(this).children().length <= 0) {
                $(this).after('<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" >' + '<li><a href="#">Edit</a></li><li><a href="#">Report</a></li><li><a href="#">Delete</a></li></ul>');
                $(this).dropdown('toggle');
            }
        });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szx4Y/283/)

Comment: Ha thanks for pointing me this . This helped me to resolve the issue